# Type Error Cannot Read Property Javascript function

Tags: javascript, node.js, mocha.js

I have a function which looks like this:

```
function instance(options) {
   this.createInstance = Bluebird.method(function() {
               this.getInstance();
    });

   this.getInstance = Bluebird.method(function () {
   });
}
module.exports = instance
```

Bluebird is a npm library for promises

In my test file using mocha, I import this instance file and create the object by `var Instance = new instance(options);`
and I call `Instance.createInstance`
However I get an error saying `TypeError: Cannot read property 'getInstance' of null`

Comment: You probably mean `this.getInstance` and not `this getInstance` - is that error in your code or is it only in the question?

Comment: @HannesJohansson That was error in question. I updated it. I meant this.getInstance

Comment: How exactly do you declare `instance` in the code that runs `instance.createInstance`?

Comment: var Instance = new instance(options);

Comment: Can you remove the `this` in front of the `getInstance()` method?

Comment: I tried that..It says getInstance not defined in that case. I have tried calling without this as well

Comment: You write `var Instance = ...` and then you invoke a function on `instance`. There's case sensitivity to consider. `instance != Instance`.

Comment: @HannesJohansson Sorry for the typos!

Comment: @HannesJohansson These typos arent there in my actual code

Comment: Can you correct the typos, and then update your question, including the code where you declare `instance` before calling `instance.createInstance`?

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't see why this code should throw that error. Are you absolutely sure that this is the actual code you're running? Can you post the whole file where you're importing the module (if it's not ridiculously long, in that case remove only the completely unrelated code)?

Comment: @HannesJohansson I added few more edits. Think the issue is because my functions are bluebird methods.

Comment: @HannesJohansson tested without bluebird. It doesnt work still

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `this` isn't available inside `Bluebird.method`. Create a new reference to `this` to fix the problem.

```
function instance(options) {
   var that = this;
   this.createInstance = Bluebird.method(function() {
               that.getInstance();
    });

   this.getInstance = Bluebird.method(function () {
   });
}
module.exports = instance
```

Comment: Thanks. I had just done this and was about to post the answer :)

Comment: Sure thing! Note that there are only three cases where the value of `this` changes: method invocations (`myobj.custommethod()`), functions called with the `new` operator (`new Instance()`), and functions called using `call `and `apply`.